# Replace columns in .csv using other .csv columns

Tags: bash, csv, awk, grep, ksh

I have 2 csv files with 15 000 lines, which looks like this:

Daily.csv

```
"CODE","BRAND","DESIGNER","SIZE","TYPE","GENDER","SET","DESCRIPTION","IMAGE","COST","WEIGHT","MSRP","UPC"
"M-1001","212","Caroline Her","1.7 oz","EDT Spray","Men","","text.","http://www.domain.com/products/Men/Final/M-1001large.jpg","31.08","1","57.00","8411061341704"
"M-1003","1881","Nino Cer","1.7 oz","EDT Spray","Men","","text.","http://www.domain.com/products/Men/Final/M-1003large.jpg","24.13","1","36.00","688575003642"
"M-1004","1881","Nino Cer","3.4 oz","EDT Spray","Men",""," text.","http://www.domain.com/products/Men/Final/M-1004large.jpg","37.51","1","50.00","688575003659"
```

GoodImages.csv

```
CODE,Images URL
M-1001,http://www.domain.com/overstock-images/M-1001arger.jpg
M-1004,http://www.domain.com/overstock-images/M-1004larger.jpg
W-C-4948,http://www.domain.com/overstock-images/W-C-4948larger.jpg
```

I need to replace field 9 "IMAGE" from Daily.csv with field 2 "Images URL" from GoodImages.csv only if both field 1 match.

```
Output is desired as:

"CODE","BRAND","DESIGNER","SIZE","TYPE","GENDER","SET","DESCRIPTION","IMAGE","COST","WEIGHT","MSRP","UPC"
"M-1001","212","Caroline Her","1.7 oz","EDT Spray","Men","","text.","http://www.domain.com/overstock-images/M-1001larger.jpg","31.08","1","57.00","8411061341704"
"M-1003","1881","Nino Cer","1.7 oz","EDT Spray","Men","","text.","http://www.domain.com/overstock-images/M-1004larger.jpg","24.13","1","36.00","688575003642"
"M-1004","1881","Nino Cer","3.4 oz","EDT Spray","Men",""," text.","http://www.domain.com/products/Men/Final/M-1004large.jpg","37.51","1","50.00","688575003659"
```

I would like to run it from a cron job if possible.

CENTOS 6.7 x86_64 standard

Thank You

Comment: I see "need" and "like" but is there a question?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am not knowledgable enough to get this done. How to do this?

Comment: This can be done with a python dictionary and some  loops. Another method if the tables were in a mySQL or sqlite database it could be done in the database with a single line `UPDATE TABLE ` query.  Neither is difficult, nor is it very interesting though.  It may be tricky to get "free help" as most people like to help others learn or at least solve interesting problems.

Comment: The URLs in line "M-1003" and "M-1004" in desired output are correct?

Comment: Shell is a command processor intended for simple automation, not a programming language for complicated tasks. Time to switch to real programming language like python, perl, java, etc..

Comment: Sorry my mistake for the desired output for line 2 it should be http://www.domain.com/overstock-images/M-1003larger.jpg for M-1003.  For M-1004 not change because they is no match with W-C-4948. I have seen people using awk for this. I am using bash as shell.

Comment: Please fix desired output in your question.

Comment: You can also use a formula in Excel when that's easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
join -a 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.10,1.11,1.12,1.13,2.2,1.9 -t, <(sort -t, -k 1,1 Daily.csv) <(sed 's/[^,]*/"&"/g' GoodImages.csv | sort -t, -k 1,1) | sed 's/,,/,/'| cut -d , -f -13 | awk -F"," '{OFS = ","; print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$13,$9,$10,$11,$12}'
```

Output:

```
"CODE","BRAND","DESIGNER","SIZE","TYPE","GENDER","SET","DESCRIPTION","Images URL","COST","WEIGHT","MSRP","UPC"
"M-1001","212","Caroline Her","1.7 oz","EDT Spray","Men","","text.","http://www.domain.com/overstock-images/M-1001arger.jpg","31.08","1","57.00","8411061341704"
"M-1003","1881","Nino Cer","1.7 oz","EDT Spray","Men","","text.","http://www.domain.com/products/Men/Final/M-1003large.jpg","24.13","1","36.00","688575003642"
"M-1004","1881","Nino Cer","3.4 oz","EDT Spray","Men",""," text.","http://www.domain.com/overstock-images/M-1004larger.jpg","37.51","1","50.00","688575003659"
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily solved by `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a["\""$1"\""]=$2;next}{if ($1 in a){$9=a[$1]}}1' FS=',' OFS=',' GoodImages.csv Daily.csv
"CODE","BRAND","DESIGNER","SIZE","TYPE","GENDER","SET","DESCRIPTION",Images URL,"COST","WEIGHT","MSRP","UPC"
"M-1001","212","Caroline Her","1.7 oz","EDT Spray","Men","","text.",http://www.domain.com/overstock-images/M-1001arger.jpg,"31.08","1","57.00","8411061341704"
"M-1003","1881","Nino Cer","1.7 oz","EDT Spray","Men","","text.","http://www.domain.com/products/Men/Final/M-1003large.jpg","24.13","1","36.00","688575003642"
"M-1004","1881","Nino Cer","3.4 oz","EDT Spray","Men",""," text.",http://www.domain.com/overstock-images/M-1004larger.jpg,"37.51","1","50.00","688575003659"
```